# Bitmap of x cm's width and y cm's height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am taking a picture using camera in my app and will email the picture to a certain email address. now i want the emailed picture's physical dimensions to be 10cm's in width and 8cm's in height. and the code i have tried is as follows:

1) declare a imageview in xml like below :

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="100mm"
    android:layout_height="80mm"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

2) and later in java file :

```
 final BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
    opts.inSampleSize = 2;
    final ImageView thumbNail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    thumbNail.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            thumbNail.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myPhoto.getPath(), opts), thumbNail.getWidth(), thumbNail.getHeight(), false));
        }
    });
```

As per the documentation the resulting bitmap should have width of 10cm's and height of 8cm's. but in xml file there is warning at these lines

```
    android:layout_width="100mm"
    android:layout_height="80mm"
     Avoid using "mm" as units (it does not work accurately on all devices); use "dp" instead.
```

so i don't have a clue as to what i should do. so please give me a solution that will work on all devices.

Comment: A warning can be ignored, though how do you expect the image to be displayed on a device with less that screen size?

Comment: it can be ignored, but what if it doesn't work on some devices. i will display the imageview in a scrollview, so it can be scrolled. i know  users may not like it but dimensions are of primary importance. is there any other way by which i can make those bitmaps to be of the dimensions i want or do u say my apporach is ok ?

Comment: You could calculate the cm/mm by using the density and the screen resolution. With that information you should know the dimension of the screen and based on that you can set the width/height to the correct values dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used WarrenFaiths directions and came up with the below solution.

```
  DisplayMetrics metrics = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
  totalDIP_X = metrics.xdpi;
  totalDIP_Y = metrics.ydpi;
```

totalDIP_X and totalDIP_Y represent the total number of DIPs per inch on the phone.

so if you want the bitmap to be 5cms*5cms on phone, which is equivalent to 1.968inch*1.968inch, we should use the below code.

```
  imageView1.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (aBitmap, (int)(1.968*totalDIP_X), (int)(1.968*totalDIP_Y), false));
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
public static int mm2pixels(int val, Context current) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = current.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, val, metrics);
}
```