# Dont scale image in imageview but show it as a fixed sized imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scaletype

anyone knows how to view an imageview of the same size across all devices?
like i have a 1.45cm by 1.45cm image...
it should be shown as 1.45x1.45 cm on all devices irrespective of their sizes...
can this be done.?
I need it to be of the same size because I am currently developing an optometry app.
my current xml layout..
/*---------------------------------*/

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.adityamhatre.project.Etest$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="14.5mm"
        android:layout_height="14.5mm"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@raw/e11" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

/*---------------------------------*/

Comment: so you already answered  your question : layout_width="14.5mm"

Comment: @pskink it isn't working but..

Comment: First of all android size is given on "dp" and "dpi" so please remove "mm".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in Android you should use `dp` to set dimensions instead of pixels/centimeters. The reason for this is because Android phone have differents densities, that is the reason why the image is not the same size on every device.

If you want to have an image of exactly 1.45cm by 1.45cm, which is 0.57 inch by 0.57 inch, you should get the density of the screen to know what is the dpi (dots by inch) of it.

By this logic, just follow this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471780/2371161

Comment: @TyMarc....
Yep. I know that. That is why I need a work around on this. I am making an optometry app that needs an Image of the same size as above given dimensions on any screen. Since the size of the image is decided by a scientific formula.